# How to use ggplot2() package in R to change the range of y-axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis

I have a qucik question. Below is my R code for ggplot2(). The name of my data is mya2021. The range of y-axis should be in [0,400000], but what the picture shows is [0e+00,4e+05]. I try to add `+ylim(0,400000)`, but it doesn't work. So I want to know how to solve this problem? Thanks very much!  [image]

```
library(ggplot2)
dev.new()
ggplot(mya2021,aes(Age.Groups,Death,fill=Year))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

Answer (score 1):

Does ir work if you add this?

```
ggplot(mya2021,aes(Age.Groups,Death,fill=Year))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = F))
```

Comment: Yes, elielink. It really works! Thank you very much!